# c# windows phone 8 app, change system volume

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8

I use WASAPI (Windows Audio Session API) in my windows phone app to play some single tone.
How i can change system volume of device, so when user click on "play" button, even if volume = 0 (muted) signal will be heard.

i tried to use ISimpleAudioVolume interface(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531(v=vs.85).aspx) but it change volume level of an audio session but if device in mute signal is not heard.

please help.

Comment: I think there is no api to do this (http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/244386-Change-system-volume-in-Windows-Phone-8)

Comment: Have you tried this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2594420

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-81-tip-master-new-custom-volume-settings

Comment: Rico Suter, I read it, but I not really understood what i need to do)